# net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in react

Tags: reactjs

[image]Whenever I try to click in the address box I get the error as too many redirects. I am unable to move forward because of this. I have cleared the cache and and browsing history still the error persists.

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit further and adding a little bit of code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.